# variables_order and REQUEST in php

Tags: php, variables

I am experimenting with php's `$_REQUEST`and then, searching around I found out about `variables_order`. I am trying to understand how those two are connected.

Now, if I got this right, lets say I have a form like

```
<form method='post'  id="some" action='some.php?name="d"&value="2"'>
    <input type="text" name="d" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Shove it"/ >
</form>
```

jQuery to submit it like

```
$('#some').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('some.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    $('#dictionary').html(data);
    });
});
```

and the `some.php` is

```
<?php
echo  $_REQUEST['d'];
?>
```

The form executes a `POST` and a `GET` at the same time, because of the `action='some.php?name="d"&value="2"'>` part. When I submit the form I get back "1" because the `variables_order` is  "GPCS". The value of the `$_REQUEST` in the some.php is at first 2 and then 1 (`GET`=2, then `POST`=1). So that is why `$_REQUEST` (which is abstarct, is not a `GET` nor a `POST`) changes from 2 to 1 -and 1 is what is echoed back.

Am I right? Did I went too far?

Problem is , I changed the `variables_order` from "GPCS" to "PGCS" and I did not got back 2, still 1. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: based on the sample URL you gave, you're setting `$_GET["name"]` and `$_GET["value"]` , ... try:  `some.php?d=2`

Comment: And technically, it doesn't execute a `POST` and a `GET` at the same time. It is only an HTTP POST, but since the URI includes a query string, PHP helpfully processes that query string to populate `$_GET` though the HTTP request itself was sent with a `POST` verb.

Comment: @JohnC You are right, thanks. I did `some.php?d=2` and I changed the `variables_order` from "GPCS" to "PGCS", I restarted apache and I still do not get back 2. Why is that?